# exporting dataset to sqlite3 database using c# application errors sqlexception unhandled

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am very new to sqlite and c# and trying  exporting a csv file to sqlite database using dataset.
 but I get this error.

```
SQL logic error or missing database
    no such column: P17JAW
```

code:

```
 string strFileName = "I:/exploretest.csv";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            DataTable tb = ds.Tables[0];
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= C:/Users/WebMobility.db; Version=3;");

         m_dbConnection.Open();
        var dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            var Id = dr["Id"].ToString();
            var VRM = dr["VehicleRegistration"].ToString();
            var Points = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TicketScore"].ToString());
            string sql = "insert into NaughtyList (Id,VRM,Points) values ( '" + Id + "'," + VRM + "," + Points + ")";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

CSV FILE CONTAINS

```
Id,VehicleRegistration,TicketScore
21,P17JAW,1
22,K1WOM,1
23,m4npr,4
25,G7EPS,4
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception, on opening connection ? Looks like your `VRM` requires single quotes around the values, not the `IDs`. Consider using parameters with your query.

Comment: that's  the reason..... solved.

Comment: how can i export a csv with quotes can you help me habib

Comment: look at my posted answer and the part where I am using parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the single quotes missing for `VRM` your query should be like:

```
string sql = @"insert into NaughtyList (Id,VRM,Points) values 
                       ( '" + Id + "','" + VRM + "'," + Points + ")";
                                    //^^          ^^
```

From the values it appears that `ID` is of integer type, you can remove single quotes around `ID`.

You should parameterized your query that will save your from these errors. I am not sure if parameters are supported by `SQLiteCommand` if they are you can do something like:

```
string sql = @"insert into NaughtyList (Id,VRM,Points) values 
                                       (@Id,@VRM,@Points)";
```

and then

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VRM", VRM);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", Points);
```